# Mobile menu not clickable when submenu is expanded

Tags: css, wordpress, mobile, menu, menuitem

I’m working on a website for a client and use the Neve theme. I setup the basics (still have to make most pages), but I noticed the mobile menu isn’t clickable when the submenu is expanded. I can’t figure out why this happened, it worked before.

On desktop the menu works like it should.

Website: https://www.by-denn.nl/

Answer (score 1):

After you click to open submenu on mobile, some div with class ".nav-clickaway-overlay" shows up. Just add this in your style.css

`.nav-clickaway-overlay { z-index: 0 !important; }`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on the pages or post when the function of "Remove unused CSS" of my WP Rocket plugin was active, once I deactivate this function the menu returned to work.
I hope this was helpful.
It is important to check page by page because even if you disable the function in the administration, it can sometimes still be connected to the page or post with the error.